# npm 9 doesn't copy js files for local dependencies

Tags: npm

My structure contains 3 projects: Client, Server and Shared. `node_models` folder is in the root and used by all these projects. Client and Server projects has dependency in packaje.json:
`"shared": "file:shared"`
So the copy of Shared project in `node_modules` folder is always actual and I'm used to have it in my build output.
But with the 9th version of `npm` I have only `.d.ts` and `.js.map` files but no `.js` files, so intellisense works well, but built project crashes because there is no js module "shared".

Is it a bug or feature?
Can I set it to work as before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm` v9 changes [`install-links` default back to true](https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/5458). Running `npm install --no-install-links` should make it work as before.

Alternatively, it sounds like your javascript files in the "Shared" project may not be being linked. To fix this, modify the [`files`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#files) field in the "Shared" project's `package.json` back to the default `["*"]`, which means it will include all files.

Comment: npm `v9.4.2` fixes the issue - https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/6142